# Delete Database records for visitor session save in database

Tags: php, mysql

May be this is a common question, but I need explanation more clearly to solve it.

I have a database creates new records for every visitor with their session. At the same time, when records being created, I put IP address, and time as well.

Problem :

When the visitor leave or close the browser and visit again, they brought new record and the previous record still there in database. I need to delete manually every time to save storage.

php to create records :

```
public function SaveVisitorData() {

    $ses_id = session_id();
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $timer  = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");  

    $query  = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `visitors`(`session`, `ipaddress`, `timer`) VALUES (?,?,?)");
    $query->bindValue(1, $ses_id);
    $query->bindValue(2, $ip);
    $query->bindValue(3, $timer);

    try {
    $query->execute();

    } catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

How to deal with $_COOKIE?

Comment: 'Deal with $_COOKIE'? You can set the cookie to expire when the visitor leaves or closes their browser.

Comment: Delete your records based on a timeout. all records 24 minutes old are garbage.

Comment: Make sense. Create a cookie and when the cookie expired execute function to delete the session recorded. I am just thinking practically in php specially how is the relationship among them. Tks

Comment: @user3706926 Did you think about REPLACE instead of INSERT so you only have 1 entry?

Comment: REPLACE? What sql "WHERE" to replace since more than one people comes with same IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a mysql delete query and delete all records where the time is older then a day?

```
mysqli_query($con,"DELETE * FROM myTable WHERE dateEntered < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);");
```

Comment: Atleast provide an example of your solution.

Comment: How about when at that time there is an active user login and making some transasction in member area? They will lost the session right?

Comment: I just want to make sure that the user leaving the blog, then DELETE can be done.

Comment: @user3706926 All you asked for was to delete old records. And you can just make it run on each script and update the time on each script. This will mean that the timer is always updated in the table. And for cookies, might want to look here: http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.setcookie.php